# Proof by Contradiction - two distinct primes not divisible by each other

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

I'm confused on how to prove by contradiction that for two distinct primes $p$ and $q$ , none of the primes can divide the other. In other words, neither $p|q$ nor $q|p$ can hold.

Answer (score 3):

This is so trivial it immediately follows by definition of prime numbers, but I will provide a proof by contradiction anyways:

Assume $p$ and $q$ are distinct prime numbers and $p|q$. Then, because $q$ is prime, $q$ has only trivial divisors, i.e. $p = 1$ or $q = p$. The case $q = p$ is not possible, since $p$ and $q$ are distinct. So therefore, we conclude that $p = 1$, but $p$ is a prime number and $1$ is not. A contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Virtually the same answer : If $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes , we can assume WLOG $p<q$ . $p|q$ means that $q$ has a non-trivial factor $p$ because of $1<p<q$ which is a contradiction because $q$ is prime. $q|p$ is not possible anyway because of $q>p$.